# Create Custom function to count unique Values in a column

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I am very new to excel VBA. I want to create a custom function =Unique(J2:J234) so that it masks the real set of functions doing the job i.e =SUM(1/COUNTIF(J2:J234,J2:J234)). This is my code below:

```
Function Unique(Var As range)
     Unique = Application.SUM(1 / (Application.COUNTIF(Var, Var)))
End Function
```

Thanks

Comment: I have tried different modifications with no results what I get is #VALUE!. Be Glad if anyone could help.

Comment: Use `Application.power(…,-1)` instead of 1/... Also you can use `with application` to avoid repetition.

Comment: did you get any improvement or solution using any suggestion upto now?

Answer (score 0):

Your UDF won't work because the original formula is an array formula (entered with ctrl-shift-enter, and there is no easy way of entering that into the UDF

I would suggest using the feature of the collection object which prevents entering items with duplicate keys:

```
Option Explicit
Function Unique(Var As Range)
    Dim V As Variant
    Dim C As Collection
    Dim I As Long
V = Var
Set C = New Collection

On Error Resume Next
For I = 1 To UBound(V, 1)
    C.Add V(I, 1), CStr(V(I, 1))
Next I
On Error GoTo 0

Unique = C.Count

End Function
```